# Как выровнять div по центру?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Без position.
Просто напишите способы (без примеров, чтобы не заморачиваться)

Comment: Погуляйте по сайтам под юзерагентом `ie7` посмотрите, какие решения предлагают сайты с поддержкой старых браузеров. Верстка через таблицы и все такое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без position:

```
div {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

либо с помощью flexbox:

С position:

```
div {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

либо

```
div { 
    top: calc(50% - р.б);
    left: calc(50% - р.б);
}
```

р.б - половина размера блока (центрируемого).

Comment: Сяб, в моём случае самый подходящий третий способ. Ост способы и так знал, а про calc что-то не подумал)

Answer (score 1):

С помощью flexbox можно.........

Comment: С помощью flex я пробовал, но минус в том, что не во всех браузерах поддерживается, а если быть точнее только в 4-7 браузерах вроде. У меня была менюшка на сайте с флексами. Так всё везде работало норм кроме старых версий браузеров и эксплорера. Хз почему, но тупо не было видно текст которому я задал color. И нет, это не из-за моей криворукости. Когда я убрал флекс, то всё заработало на ура)

Comment: Я могу понять почему их так много людей любит и мне самому нравятся и я бы их использовал всегда. Но из-за того что не все браузеры поддерживают, то нет

Comment: @andromeda Я и не настаиваю, это только один из вариантов. А вообще самый простой и который поддерживается всеми браузерами это через position

Comment: @andromeda, мне даже интересно, а какой процент пользователей вашего сайта сидят с IE9, Opera 11 и остальных тазиках?

Answer (score 0):

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью css свойства `transform: translate()`, но нужно знать размеры div и размеры родителя.